# Should I be avoiding several boolean parameters?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating ad hoc reporting solution, so I came up with a this method, its added in WCF service which will be called from front end client,

> GetEmployeeDetails(int id, bool includeAddressHistory, bool
>   includeSalaryHistory, bool includePositionHistory, bool
>   includeProjectHistory, ...never ending list)

Now issue is I need to get all of the data based on filters and then either return the complete dataset or return it as a stream, as I have another method which returns same dataset as a stream,

Comment: `Flags` enum as suggested in on of the answers (now deleted for strange reason)  would be good choice here (in my *opinion*)  - looks like you need to support combinations of multiple histories which is exactly what `Flags` enums are for - `IncludeHistoryFor.Address | IncludeHistoryFor.Salary`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am not sure how can I implement enums in this case scenario :S

Comment: Advertisement: company I work for also provides search engine (to search for topics about C# on MSDN) - try https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+flags+enum (or use any other search engine of your choice)

Comment: is this an ajax call to wcf service?

Comment: @thst Yes, but I might call it using proxy as well in future

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you need to pass a rather large number of parameters (regardless of their type), it's time to consider [parameter object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html):

```
// this is just POCO
public class SearchParameters
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
    public bool? SomeBool { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

IEnumerable<SomeEntitites> GetSomeEntitites(SearchParameters searchParameters);
```

Note, that for constructor cases the solution could be a builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if things get even more complicated is to have one class that has the EmployeeDetailsRequestParameters defined. This is particularly useful if you also do things like filtering and have a lot more than just what can fit into a flag enumerable.